# Seeding Users and Roles in Entity Framework Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm changing the way i seed data on my app using entiy framework core. Previous to 2.1 version you cannot set the identity key value so I started migrating my code but now i have a problem with seeding Users and Roles from the Identity. How can i access userManager or RoleManager on my DbContext file or modelbinder extension?

Here is how i seed users and roles using a class and inject it in program.cs

```
public class DbInitializer
{
    public static async Task Seed(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<User> userManager, RoleManager<Role> roleManager)
    {
        #region Identity
        string[] roles = new string[] { "Developer", "Super Administrator", "Administrator", "User" };

        foreach (string role in roles)
        {
            if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == role))
            {
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(new Role(role));
            }
        }


        var user = new User
        {
            Name = "test",                
            Email = "test@test.com",
            NormalizedEmail = "TEST@TEST.COM",
            UserName = "test",
            NormalizedUserName = "TEST",                
            EmailConfirmed = true,
            PhoneNumberConfirmed = false,
            SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D")
        };


        if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == user.UserName))
        {
            var password = new PasswordHasher<User>();
            var hashed = password.HashPassword(user, "development");
            user.PasswordHash = hashed;

            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user);

        }

        await AssignRoles(userManager, user.UserName, roles);
        #endregion           
    }

    public static async Task<IdentityResult> AssignRoles(UserManager<User> userManager, string userName, string[] roles)
    {            
        User user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
        var result = await userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, roles);

        return result;
    }
}
```

program file

```
        var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        var isDevelopment = environment == Environments.Development;

        if (isDevelopment)
        {
            using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<Role>>();
                var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
                await DbInitializer.Seed(context, userManager, roleManager);//<---Do your seeding here
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
            }
        }
```

now i want to start using this instead after version 2.1

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void Seed(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Author>().HasData(
            new Author
            {
                AuthorId = 1,
                FirstName = "William",
                LastName = "Shakespeare"
            }
        );
        modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasData(
            new Book { BookId = 1, AuthorId = 1, Title = "Hamlet" },
            new Book { BookId = 2, AuthorId = 1, Title = "King Lear" },
            new Book { BookId = 3, AuthorId = 1, Title = "Othello" }
        );
    }
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Seed();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inherited from `IdentityDbContext` then you can get the users table by

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Users>().HasData(
            new User
            {
            }
```